# How to re-enable Kubuntu Application Launcher Menu shortcuts after accidentally disabling

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, launcher

I just installed Kubuntu 14.04 and I'm in the process of customizing it.

I replaced the default *Application Launcher* with the traditional-style *Application Launcher Menu*. With this application launcher, you can assign shortcut keys to specific applications (by navigating to the Advanced settings for a particular application in the Edit Menu view).

I assigned shortcut keys to a few applications and tested, and everything worked. Then I went through every item in the System Settings and set my preferences. But somewhere along the way I disabled the application launcher shortcut keys. In the Menu Editor, they are still set as I defined them, and under the "Global Keyboard Shortcuts" system config in the "khotkeys" section, I also see them defined. But they just don't work anymore.

Is there some System Setting that would cause this to be disabled? How do I re-enable these shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just rubber ducked a solution here. Found the answer right after posting the question.

After pulling my hair out for an hour, I checked the Custom Shortcuts config section one more time and found a place where you can enable/disable gestures for various components. There is a *KMenuEdit* component that I had accidentally disabled.

So to re-enable application launcher shortcuts, just re-enable the gestures for the *KMenuEdit* component.